# error: C2039: 'iswspace' : is not a member of 'std', but std::isspace() compiles fine

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, compiler-errors

I encountered this weird behavior in VS2008 that I can reproduce in a fresh project with just this code:

```
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    isspace(' ');
    iswspace(L' ');
    std::isspace(' ');
    std::iswspace(L' '); // <--- ONLY THIS LINE has error
    return 0;
}
```

`std::isspace` and `iswspace` don't cause a compile error, but `std::iswspace()` does.

I don't understand why `std::isspace()` would be a member of std, but `std::iswspace()` is not. I doubt this is standards-compliant behavior.

Comment: I think you need to #include <cwctype>

Comment: @AndyM Thanks! Can you post it as an answer? Also do you know why `iswspace()` without `std::` did work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `#include <cwctype>`.

As for why the non-std ones work, they are the older versions. `<cctype>` is just `ctype.h` which has the older version of `iswspace` in it. See msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13z34da.aspx