# clang++ doesn't recognize member 'iswspace' of namespace 'std'

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-errors, clang++

I tried to compile the following `main.cpp` file with `clang++`:

```
#include <cwctype>

using std::iswspace;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

However it didn't compile, with the following error message:

```
$ clang++ main.cpp
main.cpp:3:12: error: no member named 'iswspace' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'isspace'?
using std::iswspace;
      ~~~~~^~~~~~~~
           isspace
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cctype:112:9: note: 'isspace' declared here
using ::isspace _LIBCPP_USING_IF_EXISTS;
        ^
main.cpp:3:12: error: target of using declaration conflicts with declaration already in scope
using std::iswspace;
           ^
/usr/local/include/_ctype.h:267:1: note: target of using declaration
isspace(int _c)
^
/usr/local/include/_wctype.h:105:1: note: conflicting declaration
iswspace(wint_t _wc)
^
2 errors generated.
```

Is this `clang++`'s issue?

Running `clang++ --version` gives the following:

```
$ clang++ --version
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34069375/error-c2039-iswspace-is-not-a-member-of-std-but-stdisspace-compiles) related problem and made sure to include `<cwctype>`, but it still doesn't compile. Is this `clang++`'s issue?

Comment: Compiles for me - clang, gcc, MSVC - live - https://godbolt.org/z/sh89soKeM

Comment: @RichardCritten has to be my own problem then. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: clang on Apple is a bit funny - you're probably going to need someone here who knows what's different on Apple.

Comment: It looks like your compiler is picking up headers from two different installations; the `/usr/local/include` seems out of place.